# How to add an image to canvas?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, image

I am trying to make a QGIS plugin using Python.
Right now I need way add an image to canvas but I don't want that image to be a new layer in qgis project. Is there a way to do it?

Now I have:

```
self.canvas = qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas() 
self.canvas.show()
```

But it shows only white rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

As Luigi anwered:

```
self.canvas.scene().addItem(...)
```

adds image to the canvas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a [QgsMapCanvas](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html) is a [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html) so you can add graphics items as usual in the scene of this class [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html)

regards

Comment: I am afraid I dont get it.
`self.canvas.addItem(name)`
results in 
`AttributeError: 'QgsMapCanvas' object has no attribute 'addItem'`

Comment: the scene has addItem method! self.canvas.scene().addItem(...)